# how to make a countdown timer till a certain date in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, timer

I want to write a python program that takes a certain start time from a server then increments it for a chosen interval say 1 hour and count down till reaching the end time which then a certain function will be called.

I have tried this and it works but I can't set my start time or show the timer will its counting down. is there a GUI library that can do this, any help will be appreciated. This is for an educational project.

```
delay = int(input("Enter the interval time :"))
start_time = threading.Timer(delay ,encrypt,args=('my document.docx',))
start_time.start()
```